# Create custom connection

Tags: javascript, cordova, connection, mxgraph

I want to create a specific connection between two nodes. The connection would have an image. Is this possible?

I work with mxGraph, javascript.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Simple_stock_and_flow_diagram.gif

Sorry, for my english. Thanks.

Comment: Exact copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292093/how-do-i-create-image-on-edge-in-mxgraph, one needs to be removed

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to (and I'm looking at the v2 API here) create your own edge shape, most likely based on mxConnector (in the shape folder). paintEdgeShape defines the rendering of the edge, you use the canvas API to define that drawing (see API specifications for mxAbstractCanvas2D).